# Can the @Bean function take a parameter? if so how would that parameter get set?

Tags: java, spring

I found this code that someone wrote:

```
  @Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryTemplate( long retryTimeoutMillis )
  {
    return RetryTemplateFactory.createRetryTemplate( retryTimeoutMillis );
  }
```

Can the @Bean function take a parameter? if so how would that parameter get set?

Comment: @Bean functions can take parameters that can be auto-injected, much like constructor parameters.  But I have no idea how Spring would know to auto-wire a `long` into that situation.  Strange.

Comment: I tried it myself, it will work even if the variable attribute is turned off during compilation as long as there is exactly 1 bean that qualifies for `long`

Comment: @Steve it can be an injected field in the configuration class

Comment: @NicoVanBelle - Can you show us how that would work?

Comment: I was thinking of an injected field using `@ConfigurationProperties`. If the name matches it does not need the `@Value` annotation. Furthermore the String value will be casted automatically to long by Spring. However, I have never seen such  a thing used in combination with Java configuration. I should test this, but I only have access to my mobile phone at the moment..

Comment: To come back to this; I was unable to make this work. I figured this was yet some more Spring-magic but it appears this is just too much magic, even for Spring. :D

Comment: Hi @NicoVanBelle, create a bean of long type then you should be good. In the existing code from the OP, it must be a lone bean: `@Bean long longBean() { return 0L; }`

Comment: Hi @Jayr yes it appears you are correct. I have never thought of creating a bean of a primitive type myself but it appears to be possible for some odd reason. Thank you for teaching me something new

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the comments I was able to get this to work:

```
  @Bean
  public long retryTimeoutMillis()
  {
    return 10;
  }

  @Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryTemplate( long retryTimeoutMillis )
  {
    return RetryTemplateFactory.createRetryTemplate( retryTimeoutMillis );
  }
```